Map request parameters into different POJOs / DTOs using param name "dot" attribute name with Spring Controllers
I want to implement a Spring Controller (Rest API) with a method where I can map request parameters to object attributes like this:
/my/api?filter.name=Dan&filter.age=45&filter.active=true

And in my Controller method have something like this:
@GetMapping
List<MyResult> findAll(FilterDTO filter, Pageable page) {
// some code here
}

And for the filter DTO:
@Data //lombok
public class FilterDTO {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Boolean active;
}

But in the end that won´t work as expected even if I do this:
List<MyResult> findAll(@RequestParam FilterDTO filter, Pageable page) {

or this:
List<MyResult> findAll(@RequestParam("filter") FilterDTO filter, Pageable page) {

The DTO attributes always come "null".
How can I achieve what I need?

I think the filter needs to be annotated with @ModelAttribute, or even not annotated with anything, because Spring does this by itself. And then, filter.age would assume that you have a field called filter inside your FilterDTO, trying to access its nested field age. You don't have this. Why not remove the prefix from your params?

Or if you want to keep the prefixes, you'll need to create some sort of ParamDTO that has a field called filter, of a type that has the parameters name, age and active inside it...

First of all, annotating your field with @ModelAttribute is the way to go. Even not annotating it, Spring should automatically consider it as a ModelAttribute.
Moving on to the prefixes inside your request parameters, a param that has a simple, undelimited name, like age, would assume that inside your ModelAttribute you have a field named age.
Adding a dot as a delimiter, as in the case of filter.age, assumes that inside your ModelAttribute, there is a field called filter that refers to an object that has a field age inside it. So we're talking about nested objects now.
A way for you to implement this properly would be to define a "parent DTO" ParentDTO that looks like this:
public class ParentDTO {
    private FilterDTO filter;

    // Getters and setters...
}

While your FilterDTO is unchanged from the class you already specified in your question.
Now, having ParentDTO as a ModelAttribute will map your filter.age to the age field inside your FilterDTO object.
Make sure FilterDTO also has the setters defined.

I get your point but this will not address my problem. Considering I want to be able to using as many DTOs as I need to separate different types of data I need to get from the request I don't want to be forced to create another pojo just to make that work. Specially if you take into consideration parameter "Pageable" which won´t work inside the DTO as I have already tried it. Peageable or Sort must be part of the method signature. So your suggestion is not good for my scenario. Thanks anyway.
